# Проблемка с отображением в сафари динамического бордюра

Tags: html, css, css3, safari, ul

Сделал на сайте рамки динамические для списка, красиво везде, но сафари выел мне мозг.. Прошу помощи сделать так чтобы в сафари получилось так же как и в хроме.

Вид в сафари: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вид как нужно: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
/*РАМКА*/
.what h2 {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.what .ramka-5 {
    padding: 23px;
    line-height: initial;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
    width: 177px;
}
.what .ramka-5 span:first-letter {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif; /* Гарнитура шрифта первой буквы */
    font-size: 150%; /* Размер шрифта первого символа */
    color: red; /* Красный цвет текста */
   }

/*Рамка 5*/
.ramka-5 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;  
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: initial;    
}
.ramka-5::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    left: -50%;
    top: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    background-color: #BFE2FF;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% 50%, 50% 50%;
    background-position: 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#BFE2FF, #BFE2FF), linear-gradient(#337AB7, #337AB7), linear-gradient(#BFE2FF, #BFE2FF), linear-gradient(#337AB7, #337AB7);
    animation: anim-ramka-5 4s linear infinite;
}
.ramka-5::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 6px;
    top: 6px;
    width: calc(100% - 12px);
    height: calc(100% - 12px);
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
@keyframes anim-ramka-5 {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}

/*Конец рамки 5*/
```

```html
<div class="what">
<h2>Почему мы?</h2>
<div class="ramka-5"><span class="empt">Бесплатная консультация</span></div>
<div class="ramka-5"><span class="empt">Индивидуальный план действий, детально продуманная схема</span></div>
<div class="ramka-5"><span class="empt">Юристы с дипломами лучших вузов страны </span></div>
<div class="ramka-5"><span class="empt">Работа по договору - соответственно защищённость</span></div>
<div class="ramka-5"><span class="empt">Опыт работы с 2007 года </span></div>
<div class="ramka-5"><span class="empt">Безупречная репутация = высокое качество услуг!</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Тегу span задал белый фон и растянул его по ширине до размеров внешнего блока, поиграл с отступами чтобы полоска была нужных размеров.

```css
/*РАМКА*/
.what h2 {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.what .ramka-5 {
padding: 7px;
line-height: initial;
float: left;
margin-right: 2%;
width: 199px;
}
.what .ramka-5 span:first-letter {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif; /* Гарнитура шрифта первой буквы */
    font-size: 150%; /* Размер шрифта первого символа */
    color: red; /* Красный цвет текста */
   }

/*Рамка 5*/
.ramka-5 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;  
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: initial;    
}
.ramka-5::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    left: -50%;
    top: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    background-color: #BFE2FF;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% 50%, 50% 50%;
    background-position: 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#BFE2FF, #BFE2FF), linear-gradient(#337AB7, #337AB7), linear-gradient(#BFE2FF, #BFE2FF), linear-gradient(#337AB7, #337AB7);
    animation: anim-ramka-5 4s linear infinite;
}
span.empt {
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.ramka-5::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
z-index: -2;
left: -50%;
top: -50%;
width: 200%;
height: 200%;
background-color: #BFE2FF;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 50% 50%, 50% 50%;
background-position: 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%;
background-image: linear-gradient(#BFE2FF, #BFE2FF), linear-gradient(#337AB7, #337AB7), linear-gradient(#BFE2FF, #BFE2FF), linear-gradient(#337AB7, #337AB7);
animation: anim-ramka-5 4s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes anim-ramka-5 {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}

/*Конец рамки 5*/
```

```html
<div class="what">
<h2>Почему мы?</h2>
<div class="ramka-5"><span class="empt">Бесплатная консультация</span></div>
<div class="ramka-5"><span class="empt">Индивидуальный план действий, детально продуманная схема</span></div>
<div class="ramka-5"><span class="empt">Юристы с дипломами лучших вузов страны </span></div>
<div class="ramka-5"><span class="empt">Работа по договору - соответственно защищённость</span></div>
<div class="ramka-5"><span class="empt">Опыт работы с 2007 года </span></div>
<div class="ramka-5"><span class="empt">Безупречная репутация = высокое качество услуг!</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! это ответ или дополнение к вопросу? если ответ, то, пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. если дополнение, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).